# If using policy based authentication, the first call to .net core API is forbidden

Tags: c#, .net-core, oauth-2.0, microsoft-identity-platform

I created a simple API with .NET 5.0 with a single controller action.
This action is protected with a policy:

```
[ApiController]
public class EnterpriseController : Controller
{  
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Policy = "Read")]
    [Route("customers")]
    public IActionResult GetCustomersAsync()
    {
        return Ok("Second request!");
    }        
}
```

The policy is passed if the calling token of my API contains a role "Customers.Read.All". This is done with setting the RoleClaimType to "roles":

```
        services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            var existingOnTokenValidatedHandler = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;
            options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
            {
                await existingOnTokenValidatedHandler(context);
                options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
            };
        });
```

Then I add the policy:

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Read", policy => policy.RequireRole("Customers.Read.All"));
        });
```

If I call my controller with a valid token, the first request returns "Forbidden" as a HTTP result.
If I call a second or third time, the call works as expected.
My whole example can be found [here](https://github.com/web265p3/First-request-fails).

If I remove the policy from the controller and leave only the [Authorize], a valid token is enough for the call. Now my first call is also passed on the first try.
So I am sure that my problem is about the policies...

Do you have any ideas, why my first call is always forbidden?

Update:
This is the output:

[image]

Comment: How long does it take before exception occurs?  If a proxy is being used the timeout occurs after 30 seconds.  So the fix is to set the proxy in the client to null so the proxy is ignored.

Comment: There is no exception... there is an instant "forbidden". Takes a second or less. So probably its not that...

Comment: The issue may be with the Post.  It looks like the default authorization is failing.  So maybe the first request is using the default and the second request is using the correct Customer authorization.

Comment: @jdweng How could this happen? Why shoud it use the default authorization on the first call?

Comment: Not sure if the error is in the client request or in the server.

Comment: Its definetly on the server - it does not matter who my client is. The error occurs always from all clients... webpage, postman etc.

Comment: Then maybe it is due to UserAgent which is the user default browser.  The server may not accept the browser being sent and you need to add the UserAgent to the header : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Comment: If I call my API with Postman for example a user agent header is added with the value "PostmanRuntime/7.26.8". Shouldn't this be enough?

Comment: Did you try to add same user agent in c# code?

Comment: Where can I do so? You've a reference for me?

Comment: The following webpage says "There's no easier way to kick the tires than through cURL. If you are using an alternative client, note that you are required to send a valid User Agent header in your request."  See : https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api